# How do I populate the depends_on on an aws_api_gateway_deployment resource if the aws_api_gateway_integration was created in a Terraform module?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In the Terraform docs for [`aws_api_gateway_deployment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_deployment.html) it says:

> Note: Depends on having aws_api_gateway_integration inside your rest
>   api (which in turn depends on aws_api_gateway_method). To avoid race
>   conditions you might need to add an explicit depends_on =
>   ["aws_api_gateway_integration.name"].

My `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource lives in the root module but most of the `aws_api_gateway_integration`s are created in a child module (this is a local module created by me).

My understanding is that you can't export a resource from a module.

The folder structure is:

```
 - main.tf <-- contains the aws_api_gateway_rest_api and aws_api_gateway_deployment and uses the service_func_lambda module multiple times
 - modules/
   - service_func_lambda/
     - main.tf <-- contains the aws_api_gateway_integration and other bits such as aws_api_gateway_method and aws_api_gateway_resource
```

**How can I reference the `aws_api_gateway_integration` that is created inside the module from the calling, root module?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end I made the `aws_api_gateway_deployment` depend on the whole module. This seemed to work nicely:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_gw_deploy" {

  depends_on = [
    "module.user_func_list",
    "module.user_func_create",
    "module.resource_func_list",
  ]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main_api_gw.id}"
  stage_name  = "live"
}
```

Comment: You can depend on an entire module? The more you know.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot depend on a resource inside another module. You *can* create an implicit dependency on an entire module by referencing an output of that module.

I think you can use `null_resource` for this (though there may be a better way). Create a null resource like this, then have your `aws_api_gateway_deployment` depend on it:

```
resource "null_resource" "depend_on_module" {
  triggers {
    service_func_lambda_module_output = "${module.service_func_for_lambda.some_output}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok cool. Although it feels like a bit of a hack, I guess this achieves the ultimate goal. Thanks!

Comment: On further inspection I'm not sure I follow. Do I declare that `null_resource` inside the module or outside? What does the `depends_on` attribute look like in the `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource?